# urllib.request.urlopen not giving correct source code

Tags: html, python-3.x, urllib3

I am using `urllib` to get the source code from a website and it's not giving me the same version of the source code I get when I actually open the website. For this instance I'm trying to get the source from `https://gleam.io/U7fWO/a`.

When I get the source code using `urllib`, I copy and paste it in to a file, and open it as html but it's missing some elements and shows up with a `Cookies is disabled` message rather than what it normally shows.

Is there any way for it to download the code exactly as it is in my browser?

```py
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen(i) as response:
        data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
        print(data)
```

I'm using Firefox 79.0, Python 3.7, and urllib3 1.25.10

Comment: If the page is built dynamically, it can vary from person-to-person.  When you scrape, it has no cookie to access for you.

Comment: @GAEfan is there some way to work around that so I could get the source code it has when it has access to cookies?